# Efficient way to query

Tags: parse-platform, pfquery

My app has a class that saves picture that users upload. Each object in the class has a city property that holds the name of the city that the picture was taken at, and a like property that tracks the number of likes.

I want to be able to send a query that returns one picture per city and each picture should have the highest ranking of likes in the city it belongs to. How can I do that?

One way which I first thought about is doing multiple queries by fetching the most liked picture of a city and save it in an array, and then do the same to other cities. 
However, each country has more than one city, thus it's not that efficient.

Parse doesn't support the ordinary operations used in databases. Besides, I tried to use a compound query. Unfortunately, I can't set limit or ordering on the subqueries. Any good solution for this?

Comment: Do  you know you can use subquery as just a normal query in parse?

Answer (score 3):

It would be easy using group by. Unfortunately, Parse does not support  "select distinct" or "group by" features.

As you've suggested you need to fetch for each country all the cities, and for each one get the top most rated photo.

BUT, since Parse has strict restrictions on the duration time execution of a request ( 3 sec for an event listener, 7 sec for a custom function ), I suggest you to do this in a background job, saving in a new table the top rated photo for each city. In this way you can easily query the db from client. The Background jobs can be executed up to 15 minuted before parse drop them, so you could make that kind of queries without timeouts.

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks i will investigate that! btw could that work using cloud code and javascript promises? if yes do you know any tutorial or example to promises? thanks

Comment: Yes, using Promises in series. See at https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#promises you should make the query on the country to obtain all the cities ( first query ), so fetch all cities and serialize all the query for obtain the top most photo for city, so for each top most photo you will add the resulting row to a temporary array, and finally you will update the summary table with the top most photo per city. See the Promise in series, from the link above, should helps you