# Group By Query in Parse.com Cloud Code

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm trying to get the results of the following sql command in Parse.com using cloud code.

Select shop, count(1) from Membership group by shop;

Is there a way to do so? or I can only get the number of members from selecting each shop?

```
var query = new Parse.Query("Membership");
query.equalTo("shop",shop_id);
var promise = query.find().then(function(results){
        var number_of_membership_of_one_shop = results.leng
        return results;
    });
```

Comment: you can require underscore and use _.groupBy()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse unfortunately doesn't support group by.

You could first select all shops and then use a count query for each shop.

```
var query = new Parse.Query("Membership");
query.equalTo("shop",shop_id);

var promise = query.count().then(function(count){
    var number_of_membership_of_one_shop = count;
    return number_of_membership_of_one_shop;
});
```

If this is performing too many requests, you could select all the memberships and then count them on the client, but this will have a limit of 1000 so you may need to adopt some other techniques:

```
var query = new Parse.Query("Membership");
query.select("shop_id");
query.limit(1000);
var storeCounts = [];

queryObject.find({
    success: function (results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var shopId = results[i].get('shop_id');

            if (!storeCounts[shopId]) {
                storeCounts[shopId] = 0;
            }

            storeCounts[shopId]++;
        }
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Wayne, thanks for the reply. I'm actually trying to get an array of {shop, number_of_members} from parse query API. Don't want to query the shop one by one. Is there a group_by function that I'm unaware of?

Comment: Is this what you wanted?

Comment: I think Parse.com doesn't support Group_by. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22319841/efficient-way-to-query

Comment: I think I know what you want now. I'll take a look. My answer was not the greatest

Comment: I updated my answer. You are correct, there is no groupBy. I've provided a couple of options to get the numbers that you are after.

Comment: Note that the query has default 100 and max 1000 results limitation.